# Space Drain Failing to Restage with : Failed to fetch tokens from UAA

Tags: cloud-foundry, syslog, cloudfoundry-uaa

I am deploying the space drain via the CLI and it works fine / as expected for about 10 days... and then when it attempts to restage itself when the refresh token expires I get these errors in the space drain log.

```
2019-08-09T19:32:18.897-07:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [ERR] 2019/08/10 02:32:18 starting space drain...
2019-08-09T19:32:19.044-07:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [ERR] 2019/08/10 02:32:19 Failed to fetch tokens from UAA: Unexpected status code: 401
```

Which appears to be directly related to this issue and the code sited /referenced in the issue in fact I can see the code generating the exact error.

https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cf-drain-cli/issues/21

However I read through the issue but it was unclear to me what the fix is even though the issue is closed?

If I try to restage it, it fails again the only way I get it to work is clean it up and re-deploy it with

```
cf drain-space syslog://<sysloghost>:<port> --drain-name my-space-drain
```

Then it works again until the token appears to expire ... repeat etc.

Answer (score 0):

> However I read through the issue but it was unclear to me what the fix is even though the issue is closed?

I don't see a fix on that issue either. What's explained there isn't entirely clear either. A refresh token will eventually expire. UAA doesn't let you keep one forever (at least at the time of writing). You also can't refresh a refresh token, so when it expires that's it. The only thing you can do is login again, so unless the app is storing user credentials, which it doesn't seem to be doing and would be a bad idea, it can't get another refresh token. That is probably why you hit this issue every so often.

> If I try to restage it, it fails again the only way I get it to work is clean it up and re-deploy it with

I think that's because of how the app is being configured. It looks like [it's being given a refresh token as an env variable](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cf-drain-cli/tree/develop/cmd/space_drain#configuration). Thus restaging wouldn't help.

When that token expires, you'd need to update the env variable with a new refresh token. You can get your current refresh token out of `~/.cf/config.json` (this is what the cf cli plugin is doing, see [[1]](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cf-drain-cli/blob/develop/cmd/cf-drain-cli/main.go#L62) and [[2]](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cf-drain-cli/blob/develop/internal/command/token_fetcher.go#L18). That's the refresh token for your currently logged in user using the cf cli (unless you use an alternate $CF_HOME, then it would be under $CF_HOME instead).

If you're on Linux/Mac, you can run `jq -r .RefreshToken ~/.cf/config.json` to get just the token.

Once you have the token, run `cf set-env` and update the `REFRESH_TOKEN` env variable with the new token. That should fix it and it should be a bit faster than cleaning up and redeploying.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I know I am not supposed to thanks here but I can not upvote yet, so thanks. (belated)